# Symfony simple login

Tags: symfony, authentication

i to do login in my webpage about symfony documentation example and i have a little problem. It's work but work a second time, after i clear cache. In first time i catch error with your session time out or you disabled cookie.

it's base.html.twig

```
 {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

        <div class="content">
            <div class="starter-template">
                {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    {% else %}

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-login">
                        <h4>Welcome back.</h4>
                        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="_username" id="userName" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="username" />
                            </br>
                            <input type="password" name="_password" id="userPassword" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="password" />
                            </br>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                        <span class="group-btn">

                            <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></button>
                        </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endif %}
```

and login action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

I try return redirect in this action but nothing helps me.

If login to do in /login page it's work okey. But I want use with which construction how in base.html

Comment: Do you use sonata admin bundle?

Comment: no, it's login example from http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html  , it's work in another project when i use login in /login page and then redirect after login , but now i send login data to /login from homepage

Answer (score 1):

Try work on dev mode.
1) Go on web directory
2) Open app.php file
3) Change the code inside app.php to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Remove from controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
```

Finally try move route in routing file.
For example in routing.yml:

```
login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: YourNameBundle:NameYourController:login }
```